# Adding a leading zero to a large string in Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently making an auction program in Java, I am trying to work out deadlines, however my date keeps coming out as (7/04/2013  11:22), is there a way to use String.format to add a leading zero to this date when it is a one digit day?

```
String timeOne = Server.getDateTime(itemArray.get(1).time).toString()
```

It causes me a problem later on when I try to sub string it, and it is less than 17 characters long.

Thanks in advance, James.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: I guess you're using `SimpleDateFormat` or something similar to format the date. If so, use a correct format, that *always* returns day as two-digit number. In case of `SimpleDateFormat`: `dd`.

Comment: What is the return type of Server.getDateTime()?

Comment: The date and time are stored in a Calendar item. However when I get the time from the calendar object it returns it without a leading zero.

Comment: If you'll add **all** relevant code, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Im sorry im new to all this, adding all relevant code will just make it more complicated since there are many functions involved, all I want to do is find a way to string.format a string to add a leading zero onto it. I believe this is possible I just dont understand it fully.

Comment: If there are many functions involved in formatting a date to a string, then something is seriously wrong. How are you transforming a date to a string?

Comment: itemArray.get(0).time.toString(), this literally just gets a the calendar object stored in itemArray called time and converts it to a string.

Comment: Do ***not*** try to parse the `toString` representation of a Calendar. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#toString()) - `Return a string representation of this calendar. This method is intended to be used only for debugging purposes, and the format of the returned string may vary between implementations`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the SimpleDateFormat

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

Calendar timeOne = Server.getDateTime(itemArray.get(1).time)

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")

System.out.println(sdf.format(timeOne.getTime()))
```

Comment: I am currently trying to do this:
networkOutput.println(sdf.format(timeOne));

But I get an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date

Comment: Be sure to call getTime() on the Calendar in timeOne, `sdf.format(timeOne.getTime())`

Answer (score 5):

@Leonard Brünings answer is the right way.  And here's why your original code is the wrong way ... even if it worked.

The javadoc for `Calendar.toString()` says this:

> "*Return a string representation of this calendar. This method is intended to be used only for debugging purposes, and the format of the returned string may vary between implementations.*"

Basically you are using `toString()` for a purpose that the javadoc says you shouldn't.  Even if you tweaked the output from `toString()`, the chances are that your code would be fragile.  A change in JVM could break it.  A change of locale could break it.